# exclude lines containing only numbers and whitespaces

Tags: java

I am parsing a file in java. I have few lines like this:

2756    4   3179

3076    4   3179

3142    4   3179

3179    4   3179

in my file.

I am parsing the file i java. I want to write regular expression to exclude such lines containing only numbers and white spaces.

How should I do it?

Comment: @Pshemo : I have couple of options, either to tokenize every line and check if every token contains numbers. Other option is to write regular expression and to do pattern matching. But I have never written regular expression before and just have no idea how to write it.

Comment: Before asking question on SO it is required that you at least read some tutorial. [This](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) one is very good. Also [official](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) one will show you how to use regex in Java. If you will have problem with code ask specific question like "why this code doesn't do this or that?".

Comment: @Pshemo : The editor you suggested is good for learning and understanding regular expressions. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this regular expression: **`[^\\d\\s]+[^\\n]`** (in case you are using Pattern Matcher classes)

I tested with the below program:

```
package com.stackoverflow.q20389463;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegExForNumbersAndSpaces {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("dummy text"); // Put some dummy text
        String line = System.getProperty("line.separator"); // In windows it is \n
        builder.append(line);
        builder.append("2756 4 3179");
        builder.append(line);
        builder.append("3076 4 3179");
        builder.append(line);
        builder.append("another one");
        builder.append(line);
        builder.append("3142 4 3179");
        builder.append(line);
        builder.append("3179 4 3179");
        builder.append(line);
        builder.append("and another one");

        System.out.println("SOURCE --BEGIN--"
                + line + builder
                + line + "SOURCE --END--");
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\d\\s]+[^\\n]", Pattern.MULTILINE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(builder.toString());
        System.out.println(line + "OUTPUT --BEGIN--");
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.print(matcher.group());
        }
        System.out.println(line + "OUTPUT --END--");
    }
}
```

and it output the below:

```
SOURCE --BEGIN--
dummy text
2756 4 3179
3076 4 3179
another one
3142 4 3179
3179 4 3179
and another one
SOURCE --END--

OUTPUT --BEGIN--
dummy text
another one
and another one
OUTPUT --END--
```